Linux mint cinnamon
Been to trying install linux mint cinnamon on my lenovo thinkpad X1 carbon 9th gen and it doesn't work , it glitches and freezes screen during the installation process
tried manjaro and still the same issue.

Please [edit] your question and give us more details. When, exactly, do the errors occur? Does it always happen at the same time? What do they look like? Can you show a picture? What is your hardware (Lenovo laptops are configurable, so the X1 isn't enough; in any case, don't force people to need to go and look up your hardware, make it easy for them to answer by including the info here).
